# Disable software inserting firewall rules

Tags: firewall, ufw

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Postfix, Dovecot and UFW,
when installing both Postfix and Dovecot I immediately noticed they're adding their own rules into iptables, however using the UFW commands I can't override those since those rules are above

```
root@example:~# iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
```

Now this won't allow me to e.g. completely block abusive IPs, removing the rules doesn't help since they're back as soon as the server reboots, my question is if (preferably) there is a way for me to disable these rules being added and just include them in UFW, or do I have to block the IPs using iptables?

Comment: I've never seen Postfix nor Dovecot do that. Are you sure that's not just the package installing UFW configurations?

Comment: @user1686 do you mean as in UFW installs these rules itself in the iptables or that apt does? If it was apt it wouldn't explain why they're back when rebooted

Comment: UFW has the concept of premade "application profiles", and I remember seeing some Debian/Ubuntu packages installing files into `/etc/ufw` listing predefined ports for each application that UFW then automatically adds rules for. Check if Ubuntu does that for Postfix.

Comment: @user1686 I've temporarily removed the port allow rules from UFW and removed all files from `/etc/ufw/applications.d/`, `cat /etc/ufw/*.* | grep 587` shows no matches, doesn't seem like UFW's fault